# How to display a custom form in Outlook vsto on custom action?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a simple Outlook 2016 VSTO with a custom ribbon that contains a button and one custom form. I am currently trying to figure out how to display the custom form I created in button click action. I tried instantiating a new form of the custom form (FormAddGroups) type and .Show(); it, but there is something in the constructor I don't understand.

```
formAddGroups = new FormAddGroups(xxx);
formAddGroups.Show();
```

It asks me for a formRegion from the current project in the xxx arguement, but I'm not quite sure how to access it, or if it's even the right way of showing it.

I'm also considering creating a custom message class on that button click, but I'm not sure if that's even possible.

Is that the right approach or should I go back?

Answer (score 0):

Call `MAPIFOlder.Items.Add("IPM.Note.MyCustomClass")` to create the new item and display it (`MailItem.Display`).

Comment: I was specifically focused on a custom form I created. I'm not quite sure how to implement what you suggested. Is "MyCustomClass" the name of the form I want to add? If so, then shouldn't MailItem be of the same name, if that's the form I want to display?

Comment: Also MAPIFolder is an interface, I don't think you can reference it like this?

Comment: I thought you are creating a custom form region. I am not sure what the problem is showing a custom form - you of that same as in a Windows app. You'll just need to make sure you provide the right HWND of the Outlook window.

Comment: What is the MAPIFolder in your code and IPM.Note.MyCustomClass? Do you have to create that class somewhere before? It seems like MAPIFolder object is not present in my project, only the interface which I can't reference in the way you've shown.

Comment: MAPIFolder is something you retrieve from Outlook, e.g. using Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder.  "IPM.Note.MyCustomClass" is a message class for yoru custom from (if that is what yo uare using). If you want to create a regular mail item, it is "IPM.Note"

Comment: But isn't Outlook.MAPIFolder outdated? Shouldn't I just be able to use Outlook.Folder to access the current folder? But Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder is of different type.

Comment: The two are the same.

Comment: Could you give me an example of properly implementing GetDefaultFolder for MAPIFolder in Outlook? After spending all this time looking for it I haven't found anything.

Comment: Show you code and describe the error you are getting back.